# What was the first movie to show a crazy person's wall covered with photos & articles connected by colored yarn?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

In movies such as *A Beautiful Mind*, a crazy / obsessed person will cover a wall with photographs and news articles, and connect them with colored yarn. (This is called [link analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_analysis)). We've all seen this a bunch of times, but what was the first movie to use this trope?

[image]

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49575/what-is-the-point-of-the-red-thread-tape-around-evidence-or-newspaper-clippings/49586#49586

Comment: Are you actually interested specifically in the first instance of *a crazy/obsessed person* doing this, or would examples where it is done by perfectly rational people just doing their jobs also count?  Or are all police detectives and private eyes being classified as "obsessive" due to the nature of their work?  *Please note:* I don't intend this comment to sound mean-spirited, I'm just not sure if the person's mental state is really part of the question you want answered.

Comment: @Steve-O I'm asking about a "crazy" person doing this as part of their obsession. (Good question! And I didn't take it as mean-spirited. ;-)  )